# Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an > interface from

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I migrated my android Application to AndroidX (From menu Refactor-> Migrate to androidX), Now When I run the application it's working fine but when I try to generate signed .apk file I am getting an error like

```
Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdb.

Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from com.google.android.gms.internal.zzii.

Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcms.
```

[image]

Here is the List of dependencies I am using on my application,

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('com.android.support:support-annotations:29.0.0')
    implementation "com.android.support:design:29.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar' //For view pager circle

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    implementation project(":photoview")

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Update all of the dependencies in your app to the latest available.

Comment: @DougStevenson Let me try

Comment: @DougStevenson  Now I am getting  " ERROR: All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0
Open File "
But I am using Latest Version of firebase library on my project

Comment: By executing the gradle task `dependencies` you can get a dependency tree. It might be some other library which is importing older firebase versions. (Also check your libs folder for any other libraries which might create conflict)

Comment: Please edit the question to show all the dependencies in your build.gradle.  You are probably still not updating something to the latest.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated question with dependencies  I added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely the cause of your problem:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

In fact, this dependency is **very** out of date.  You should actually just remove it completely and let firebase-messaging just pull in what it needs.

If you need to use any specific play-services library, you should use one of the new, more granular ones listed here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases